# Why do I still have to specify NEXT USED for my single-filegroup SQL Server Partition?

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

I declared a Partition Scheme:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PartitionedValuationDatesScheme AS PARTITION PartitionedValuationDates ALL TO ([PRIMARY])
```

And I make and create Ranges:

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PartitionedValuationDates() SPLIT RANGE (5)
or
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PartitionedValuationDates() MERGE RANGE (79)
```

But I always have to declare `NEXT USED` after every change:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PartitionedValuationDatesScheme NEXT USED [PRIMARY]
```

otherwise the *next* range operation fails with:

> Warning: The partition scheme 'PartitionedValuationDatesScheme' does not have any next used filegroup. Partition scheme has not been changed.

Why do I still need to do this, after defining the Scheme as `ALL ON ([PRIMARY])`? Shouldn't that make the `NEXT USED` unnecessary?

**Am I doing something wrong?** Or is just TheWayThingsAre?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong; the behavior is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-partition-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments). Note the initial creation of the scheme with `ALL TO` does not preclude creating new partitions on different filegroups and the specification is not persisted. Consider submitting a [feedback feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) If you don't care for the existing behavior.

Comment: It's good practice to do this *before* the `ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION`, not after, so you know what filegroup is affected. And yes, that T-SQL forces you to be explicit about this even when there's no ambiguity is clunky.